# Regex for a syntax colouring scheme

Tags: regex

I'm working on a syntax coloring scheme for my favourite programming language, OOREXX. The language isn't important, as my question is purely about a REGEX.

Simple description: A regex to match any of a bunch of words, but they must have a "~" prefix or a "(" suffix or both

Full description:
I want to match any of a bunch or words. They are the names of functions. This is easy, something like:

(stream|Strip|Substr) etc.

But the word "strip" (for example) might occur in my code when not a function name:

Strip = 1    -- Set variable "Strip" to 1

So, I need to be more precise. The function names must have either a leading "~" or a trailing "(" or both

This is where my REGEX skill fails. I could get around this in my colouring scheme by using two elements, one to catch "~strip" and one to catch "strip(" but that means duplicating, and maintaining, the list of function names. That goes against the grain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use alternation. In case lookbehinds are supported, you can use

```
(?<=~)strip|strip(?=\()
```

If you want something fancy and your regex engine supports lookbehind and if clauses, you can avoid alternation - though it won't be any more performant, e.g.

```
((?<=~))?strip(?(1)|(?=\())
```

And if you don't have lookbehinds, you can still use grouping and extract from the captured groups, e.g.

```
~(strip)|(strip)\(
```

Comment: Thanks! In your first expression, "strip" appears twice. In my version it would be (...stream|strip|substr...) for about 70 alternatives. So, I'd be back duplicating the list of names.

I'm going to try the second expression, if it works in my  editor.

Comment: Expression #2 worked in my EditPadPro syntax colouring scheme "as is".

My O'Reilly "Mastering Regular Expressions" calls lookbehinds "Backreferences" and uses \1 as the reference, calling it a metasequence. 

This caused me a significant bout of confusion, hence the delay coming to the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend (over & over) using http://regexr.com to test Regular Expressions.  I am not affiliated with them, but I program regular expressions 8 hours a day (sometimes)...  It's a nice tool for practicing them.... ***But*** to answer your question (in Java)...

**Also** Make sure to view the screen-capture-image after the code below.

```
// If there is a matching function name within this string, this will
// return that name, otherwise, it will return null.
public static String functionName(String functionNameStr)
{
    // This Regular Expression Groups the symbols before, or after, or both!
    // No, really, that's what it says...

    String  RE = "(~\\w+|\\w+\\)|~\\w+\\))";

    // NOTE: In Java, escape characters need to be Escaped Twice!
    // ALSO NOTE: This version puts a "precedence" on catching both symbols!
    // RE = "(~\\w+\\)|~\\w+|\\w+\\))"
    // Since the ~func-name) is listed first, if both symbols are included,
    // it will catch that too.  Maybe this is relevant to your code/question.

    Pattern P1 = Pattern.compile(RE);
    Matcher m  = P1.matcher(functionNameStr); 
    if (m.find())  return m.group();
    else           return null;
}
```

[Click Here to see Screen Capture Image of Regular Expressions processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Svod.png)